# Launching Activity from view taking too much time

Tags: android

I have coded a custom view and in this view, I have a method. When this method (`launchTestActivity`) is called, I would like it to launch another activity.

Currently my method looks like this:

```
private void launchTestActivity() {
Context ctx = getContext();
        Intent intent = new Intent(ctx.getApplicationContext(), DeathScreenActivity.class);
        ctx.startActivity(intent);
}
```

However when this method is called, it takes a time to switch to the new activity (which is just a blank screen) and I get a logcat message saying the application is skipping frames.

What do you suggest I should do?

Comment: There's no reason to call ctx.getApplicationContext, just pass in ctx.  But the problem with time is going to be anything else going on in this activity or in the new one's startup, not this.

Comment: What happens in the new activity's `onCreate()` method? This is most likely where the cycles are being used.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Nothing is happening in the new activity's `onCreate()`, as of now it is just a blank screen. However the view in my old activity from which I am calling `launchTestActivity()` is a custom view that is drawing a game.

Comment: Probe what happens in dirty way: from view set flag in main activity (public boolean something;) and in main activity in Runnable() loop with postDelayed(this, 100); check this flag, set to false and fire activity if flag is set. Effect the same or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out since I was calling `launchTestActivity()` from within a `if` statement that was being tested everytime `onDraw()` was being called I was calling `launchTestActivity()` multiple times and thus launching the new activity multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty sure it might be just your CPU or your memory that is taking a while to call this function. You are calling it correctly anyway.

Answer (score 0):

The application may be doing too much work on its main thread. You should check for any heavylifting in the DeathScreenActivity.

Comment: DeathScreenActivity has nothing in it, however the view in which I am calling `launchTestActivity()` is repeatedly calling `onDraw()`, do you think this would be the problem?

Comment: You may be setting background of the views, or trying to show complex animations. Try to explain more about the actual work in these two activities

Comment: I am doing no work in the DeathScreenActivity, however the activity that launches DeathScreenActivity contains a view that is doing lots of computations for a game.